# What's wrong with this Chez Scheme FFI call to user32.dll SendInput?

Tags: scheme, racket

I've never had any trouble with Chez Scheme FFI before, it's extremely forgiving with whatever you throw at it, but I can't seem to get this function not to throw errors.

The goal is to simply virtually press and release the left windows key.

```
(load-shared-object "user32.dll")

(define-ftype win32-input-ftype
  (struct (type unsigned-long)
      (mi (union (dx long)
             (dy long)
             (mouseData unsigned-long)
             (dwFlags unsigned-long)
             (time unsigned-long)
             (dwExtraInfo uptr)))
      (ki (union (wVk unsigned-short)
             (wScan unsigned-short)
             (dwFlags unsigned-long)
             (time unsigned-long)
             (dwExtraInfo uptr)))
      (hi (union (uMsg unsigned-long)
             (wParamL unsigned-short)
             (wParamH unsigned-short))))) 
;; Struct info from MSDN
;; dwExtraInfo is actually an (* unsigned-long), but creating a dummy ulong pointer set to 0
;; also had no effect. A nullable uptr is also interchangeable in working code for other ffi calls

(define-ftype input-array-ftype
  (array 2 win32-input-ftype)) ;; win32-input-ftype/INPUT[2]

(define send-input-fp
  (foreign-procedure "SendInput"
             (unsigned-int
              (* input-array-ftype)
              int)
             unsigned-int)) 
;; Define signature for SendInput from MSDN

(define input-array
  (make-ftype-pointer input-array-ftype
   (foreign-alloc (ftype-sizeof input-array-ftype)))) 
;; Allocate the array with the structs and create a pointer to it

(ftype-set! input-array-ftype
        (0 type) input-array 1) ;; input_array[0].type = 1;
(ftype-set! input-array-ftype
        (0 ki wVk) input-array #x5B) ;; input_array[0].ki.wVk = 0x5B;
(ftype-set! input-array-ftype
        (0 ki wScan) input-array 0) ;; input_array[0].ki.wScan = 0;
(ftype-set! input-array-ftype
        (0 ki dwFlags) input-array 0) ;; input_array[0].ki.dwFlags = 0;
(ftype-set! input-array-ftype
        (0 ki time) input-array 0) ;; input_array[0].ki.time = 0;
(ftype-set! input-array-ftype
        (0 ki dwExtraInfo) input-array 0) ;; input-array[0].dwExtraInfo = NULL;

(ftype-set! input-array-ftype
        (1 type) input-array 1) ;; input_array[1].type = 1
(ftype-set! input-array-ftype
        (1 ki wVk) input-array #x5B) ;; input_array[1].ki.wVk = 0x5B;
(ftype-set! input-array-ftype
        (1 ki wScan) input-array 0) ;; input_array[1].ki.wScan = 0;
(ftype-set! input-array-ftype
        (1 ki dwFlags) input-array 2) ;; input_array[1].ki.dwFlags = 2;
(ftype-set! input-array-ftype
        (1 ki time) input-array 0) ;; input_array[1].ki.time = 0;
(ftype-set! input-array-ftype
        (1 ki dwExtraInfo) input-array 0) ;; input_array[1].ki.dwExtraInfo = NULL;

(display (send-input-fp 2 input-array
            (ftype-sizeof win32-input-ftype)))

;; The return is 0 for all events failing and GetLastError is 87 invalid parameters.
;; Recursing through the structs show they're all allocated as expected and the ftype-sizeof
;; is in the expected area as well.
```

And here's the working C++ code that I'm trying to mimic:

```
void PressWindowsKey()
{
    INPUT inputs[2] = {};
    INPUT *input_ptr = inputs;

    inputs[0].type = 1;
    inputs[0].ki.wVk = 0x5B;
    inputs[0].ki.wScan = 0;
    inputs[0].ki.time = 0;
    inputs[0].ki.dwFlags = 0;
    inputs[0].ki.dwExtraInfo = NULL;

    inputs[1].type = 1;
    inputs[1].ki.wVk = 0x5B;
    inputs[1].ki.wScan = 0;
    inputs[1].ki.time = 0;
    inputs[1].ki.dwFlags = 2;
    inputs[1].ki.dwExtraInfo = NULL;

    UINT uSent = SendInput(2, input_ptr, sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!
This is on stand-alone 32-bit/64-bit Chez Scheme 9.5.4 (I've tried both), but I'm attaching Racket to the tags since if I'm not mistaken the Chez hosted within has the same FFI.

Answer (score 1):

The code almost works as is, but as mentioned in the Chez Scheme documentation, allocating arrays is conservative in the number of bytes is uses. SendInput is also very particular about arg 3 being the exact number of bytes.

By manually typing in 28 bytes for arg 3 of SendInput instead of using (ftype-sizeof), the program works.

Edit:
I got some strange behavior from the (unions as well. Switching the foreign type definition to:

```
(define-ftype win32-input-ftype
  (struct (type unsigned-long)
      (ki (struct (wVk unsigned-short)
              (wScan unsigned-short)
              (dwFlags unsigned-long)
              (time unsigned-long)
              (dwExtraInfo uptr)))))
```

fixed this problem. Good luck